# Are the Spherical harmonics the S^2 equivalent of the exp(i \pi n) function series?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplacian, spherical-harmonics

As I understand it, the Spherical harmonics and the "Fourier functions" $\exp(i\pi n)$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ have much in common:

- Both are eigenfunctions of the angle part of the Laplace operator.
- Both form a complete and orthonormal base of the functions on the sphere in their dimension ($S^1$ and $S^2$).

Are the spherical harmonics **the** $S^2$ analogon of the Fourier functions, or is there some important difference?

Comment: One important difference is that $S^2$ is not, say, a locally compact abelian group, so there isn't, strictly speaking, a Fourier transform on it. (So, for example, one property of the usual Fourier transform is that it intertwines pointwise multiplication and convolution. But what does convolution mean on $S^2$?)

Comment: They are analogous in the way you have stated. These sets diagonalize the Laplacian in the precise sense of the Spectral Theorem. Thus, for example, $f$ is in the domain of the respective operator iff $\sum_{n}\lambda_n^{2}|(f,e_n)|^{2} < \infty$, where $\lambda_n$ is the eigenvalue of the $e_n$.